# Count Re-occurrence of a value in python

Tags: python, pandas, loops, count

I have a data set which contains something like this:

```
SNo  Cookie
1       A
2       A
3       A
4       B
5       C
6       D
7       A
8       B
9       D
10      E
11      D
12      A
```

So lets say we have 5 cookies **'A,B,C,D,E'**. Now I want to count if any cookie has reoccurred after a new cookie was encountered. For example, in the above example, cookie **A** was encountered again at 7th place and then at 12th place also. **NOTE** We wouldn't count A at 2nd place as it came simultaneously, but at position 7th and 12th we had seen many new cookies before seeing A again, hence we count that instance. So essentially I want something like this:

```
Sno Cookie  Count
 1     A     2
 2     B     1
 3     C     0
 4     D     2
 5     E     0
```

Can anyone give me logic or python code behind this?

Comment: How your data set looks like in a representation is not as interesting as a piece of code which sets a suitable data structure up to contain it. This is not the same as making a [mcve], but similar and serves similar purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this would be to first get rid of consecutive `Cookies`, then find where the `Cookie` has been seen before using `duplicated`, and finally `groupby` cookie and get the sum:

```
no_doubles = df[df.Cookie != df.Cookie.shift()]

no_doubles['dups'] = no_doubles.Cookie.duplicated()

no_doubles.groupby('Cookie').dups.sum()
```

This gives you:

```
Cookie
A    2.0
B    1.0
C    0.0
D    2.0
E    0.0
Name: dups, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Hey thanks.. But I think your answer works for cookie comes simultaneously 2 times, what if it comes more than 2 times lets say 5 times? Then what will be the logic?

Comment: That will still work, because the code to create `no_doubles` will get rid of consecutive Cookies, regardless of whether there are 2 or 200000 consecutively

Comment: Man! You just saved me my job. That worked so smoothly! Thanks a ton buddy :)

Comment: Done! Thank you. Could you also help me in upvoting my answer? I am new here and had 2 bad questions asking by the community. It will help me. Thank you.

Comment: You already have my +1 (this I guess was counter-acted by someone else's downvote...)

Comment: Hey could you see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52083723/count-re-occurrence-of-a-value-in-python-aggregated-with-respect-to-another-valu

Answer (score 2):

Start by removing consecutive duplicates, then count the survivers:

```
no_dups = df[df.Cookie != df.Cookie.shift()] # Borrowed from @sacul
no_dups.groupby('Cookie').count() - 1
#        SNo
#Cookie     
#A         2
#B         1
#C         0
#D         2
#E         0
```

Comment: DYZ Can a code like this do the count here:?`df.groupby('Cookie').size().reset_index(name='Count')`

Comment: Your code will not eliminate consecutive duplicates.

Comment: DYZ can you help solving me this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52083723/count-re-occurrence-of-a-value-in-python-aggregated-with-respect-to-another-valu

Answer (score 1):

#### `pandas.factorize` and `numpy.bincount`

1. If immediately repeated values are not counted then remove them.
2. Do a normal counting of values on what's left.
3. However, that is one more than what is asked for, so subtract one.

---

1. `factorize`
2. Filter out immediate repeats
3. `bincount`
4. Produce `pandas.Series`

---

```
i, r = pd.factorize(df.Cookie)
mask = np.append(True, i[:-1] != i[1:])
cnts = np.bincount(i[mask]) - 1

pd.Series(cnts, r)

A    2
B    1
C    0
D    2
E    0
dtype: int64
```

---

#### `pandas.value_counts`

`zip` cookies with its lagged self, pulling out non repeats

```
c = df.Cookie.tolist()

pd.value_counts([a for a, b in zip(c, [None] + c) if a != b]).sort_index() - 1

A    2
B    1
C    0
D    2
E    0
dtype: int64
```

---

#### `defaultdict`

```
from collections import defaultdict

def count(s):
  d = defaultdict(lambda:-1)
  x = None
  for y in s:
    d[y] += y != x
    x = y

  return pd.Series(d)

count(df.Cookie)

A    2
B    1
C    0
D    2
E    0
dtype: int64
```