# Merge multiple rows (having some non string values) with same ID into one delimited row in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, count, logic, grouping

I have a dataset like this:

```
ID    Name
 1       a
 1       b
 1       2
 1       3
 2      er
 2     get
 2  better
 3     123
 3    cold
 3    warm
 3   sweet
 3    heat
```

and I want to group together this data such that data column "name" having same "id" is merged together using a delimiter. Something like this:

```
ID                      Name
 1                   a,b,2,3
 2             er,get,better
 3  123,cold,warm,sweet,heat
```

and so on.

Can anyone provide me a pythonic way of doing this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pandas - Merge nearly duplicate rows based on column value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36271413/pandas-merge-nearly-duplicate-rows-based-on-column-value)

Comment: I tried doing that but I always get this error "sequence item 6: expected str instance, float found"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `','.join` in a `groupby`

```
df.groupby('ID').Name.apply(','.join)

ID
1                     a,b,c,d
2               er,get,better
3    hot,cold,warm,sweet,heat
Name: Name, dtype: object
```

---

Reset the index if  you need those same two columns

```
df.groupby('ID').Name.apply(','.join).reset_index()

   ID                      Name
0   1                   a,b,c,d
1   2             er,get,better
2   3  hot,cold,warm,sweet,heat
```

If for some reason you have non string items

```
df.assign(Name=df.Name.astype(str)).groupby('ID').Name.apply(','.join).reset_index()

   ID                      Name
0   1                   a,b,c,d
1   2             er,get,better
2   3  hot,cold,warm,sweet,heat
```

Comment: I get this error : sequence item 6: expected str instance, float found

Comment: Then you have items in the `Name` column that are not strings.  I've updated answer

Comment: Amazing! I was not able to catch this. Thanks a ton. Can you also help me upvote my question :)

Comment: I won't upvote on request.  But as it happens, I already have.  You have one downvote and one upvote which nets to zero.